# date_select Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datepicker

How do I extend the range of the date_select in [Ruby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29)?

It only goes as far as 2005 and I'd like to use it for the date of birth.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the `:start_year` option, see [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#M001698).

Answer (score 6):

```
<%= f.date_select :exp_date, :start_year=>2000,:end_year=>2030 %>
```

it will display `2000 to 2030 years..`

if u want more you can change the `:start_year and :end_year values.`